# Bye-rule in the reykjavic open

Tags: tournament

I am confused about the bye-rule in the reykjavic tournament. If I understand it
 right, a player can take a half point for free under some conditions.

- Does anyone know the exact rules ?
- What is the sense of this rule ?

Answer (score 2):

The exact rules are on the [tournament rules](http://www.reykjavikopen.com/info/tournament-rules/) page. If your schedule does not permit you to play every game or you just need some rest, you can can take a half-point bye instead, getting 1/2 point instead of playing. This is pretty much the same bye rule used in every Swiss System tournament.